# Lowercase this array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, format

```
    [
  [],
  [ 'Tên', 'Lần 1', 'Lần 2', 'Lần 3', 'Lần 4', 'Tổng' ],
  [ 'Tom', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1' ],
  [ 'Bradey', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ 'Mike', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ],
  [ 'Luke', '1', '0', '0', '1', '2' ],
  [ 'Cooper', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1' ],
  [ 'Jason', '0', '1', '0', '1', '2' ],
  [ '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ],
  [ '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ],
  [ '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ],
  [ '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ],
  [ '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ],
  ... 200 more items
]
```

Is there a way to lowercase this entire array but still keep it the same? Help me please thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested calls using `map()` function.

```js
result = array.map(subarray => subarray.map(string => string.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: what about PO demand on " still keep it the same" ?

Comment: The structure is the same. I didn't interpret that as meaning "in place", although that's a possible meaning.

Answer (score 0):

for **still keep it the same** use:

```js
const array2d = 
  [ [ 'Tên', 'Lần 1', 'Lần 2', 'Lần 3', 'Lần 4', 'Tổng'] 
  , [ 'Tom', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1'] 
  , [ 'Bradey', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1'] 
  , [ 'Mike', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] 
  , [ 'Luke', '1', '0', '0', '1', '2'] 
  , [ 'Cooper', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1'] 
  , [ 'Jason', '0', '1', '0', '1', '2'] 
// ...
  ]; 
array2d.forEach(subArr=>subArr.forEach((el,i,arr)=>arr[i]=el.toLowerCase()))
  
console.log(array2d)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is away of many that's for sure

```
const r = [
      [],
      ["Tên", "Lần 1", "Lần 2", "Lần 3", "Lần 4", "Tổng"],
      ["Tom", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1"],
      ["Bradey", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1"],
      ["Mike", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
      ["Mike", "Bradey", "Tom", "Tên", "DFHDFH", "0FHGDJFGJ"],
    ];
    let newr = [];
    for (let s of r) {
      newr = r.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
    console.log(newr);
```